# What does Collections.shuffle function do

Tags: java, arraylist

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWT6C.png)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SynchronizedObjEffectArea {
  interface Func {
    void run();
  }

  private volatile int index = 0;
  private static final int size = 20000;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Func> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
    final SynchronizedObjEffectArea obj = new SynchronizedObjEffectArea();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      threadList.add(obj::task1);
      threadList.add(obj::task2);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(threadList);

    for (final Func thread : threadList) {
      thread.run();
    }
  }

  private void task1() {
    synchronized (SynchronizedObjEffectArea.this) {
      index = index + 1;
    }
  }

  private void task2() {
    synchronized (SynchronizedObjEffectArea.this) {
      index = index + 1;
      if (index == size * 2) {
        System.out.println("index: " + index);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the code like above, i usually can got the output "index: 40000" or sometimes can not.

By comment out the code `Collections.shuffle(threadList);`, the code works fine, it always output "index: 40000"

I confuse that what shuffle function do cause the result like above? Can anyone explain this?

Comment: 1. Please, don't post images of the code, where you can post *code itself*, as a raw text; 2. Post formatted code, as the readability will be better.

Comment: `Randomly permutes the specified list using a default source of randomness.` - from the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))

Comment: "Can anyone explain this?" Why are you shuffling at all?

Comment: If you want to start a thread, that's `thread.start()`, not `thread.run()`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica this code doesn't use threads. The naming is misleading.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Oh, hey, you're right. It was most likely *supposed* to use threads, but it doesn't, and it's going to take more than just switching `run` to `start` to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're really asking about what `Collections.shuffle` does in general: I think you're asking why `Collections.shuffle` affects the output:

You are creating a load of tasks of two kinds: one of them increments a value ("kind 1"); the other increments a value and sometimes prints a message ("kind 2"). These are put into a list, and executed sequentially.

If you put an equal number of these two kinds of tasks into a list, shuffle them, and execute them sequentially, the item at a position is going to be a "kind 1" task 50% of the time, and a "kind 2" task the rest of the time.

Since "kind 2" tasks only prints for a specific value, you will only get something printed if it is a "kind 2" task at position `2 * size - 1`, which will be 50% of the time.

If you don't shuffle them, but add "kind 1" and "kind 2" in turn, the item at position `2 * size - 1` will always be a "kind 2", so it will always print.

Answer (score 0):

[Collections.shuffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) Randomly permutes the specified list using a default source of randomness. All permutations occur with approximately equal likelihood.

So if tasks ar shuffled, sometimes task2 run first and then output is different.

Answer (score 0):

This is the javadoc and source code for java.util.Collections.shuffle():

```
/**
 * Randomly permute the specified list using the specified source of
 * randomness.  All permutations occur with equal likelihood
 * assuming that the source of randomness is fair.<p>
 *
 * This implementation traverses the list backwards, from the last element
 * up to the second, repeatedly swapping a randomly selected element into
 * the "current position".  Elements are randomly selected from the
 * portion of the list that runs from the first element to the current
 * position, inclusive.<p>
 *
 * This method runs in linear time.  If the specified list does not
 * implement the {@link RandomAccess} interface and is large, this
 * implementation dumps the specified list into an array before shuffling
 * it, and dumps the shuffled array back into the list.  This avoids the
 * quadratic behavior that would result from shuffling a "sequential
 * access" list in place.
 *
 * @param  list the list to be shuffled.
 * @param  rnd the source of randomness to use to shuffle the list.
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the specified list or its
 *         list-iterator does not support the <tt>set</tt> operation.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (size < SHUFFLE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
    } else {
        Object arr[] = list.toArray();

        // Shuffle array
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(arr, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));

        // Dump array back into list
        // instead of using a raw type here, it's possible to capture
        // the wildcard but it will require a call to a supplementary
        // private method
        ListIterator it = list.listIterator();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            it.next();
            it.set(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

So, as out common knowledge of the English language tells us, shuffle will randomly re-order the contents of the Collection you specify.

That's also what the javadoc says.

So seeing you have this problem, next time

- Look up the English term in a translator or dictionary
- Use an IDE. That will show you the javadoc for the methods, and as a bonus it will do the formatting of your source code for you
- Run a test with 3-10 items on a list, this will also show you what happens